# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - tmp/pids/puma.pid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

I'm trying to start puma, but at the last step it fails like this:

```
16:38:09 web.1  | /home/ramonpm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:130:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - tmp/pids/puma.pid (Errno::ENOENT)
16:38:09 web.1  |   from /home/ramonpm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:130:in `open'
16:38:09 web.1  |   from /home/ramonpm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:130:in `write_pid'
16:38:09 web.1  |   from /home/ramonpm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:103:in `write_state'
16:38:09 web.1  |   from /home/ramonpm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/single.rb:92:in `run'
16:38:09 web.1  |   from /home/ramonpm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:174:in `run'
16:38:09 web.1  |   from /home/ramonpm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:77:in `run'
16:38:09 web.1  |   from /home/ramonpm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/gems/puma-3.9.1/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
16:38:09 web.1  |   from /home/ramonpm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/bin/puma:23:in `load'
16:38:09 web.1  |   from /home/ramonpm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
16:38:09 web.1  |   from /home/ramonpm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
16:38:09 web.1  |   from /home/ramonpm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
16:38:09 web.1  | exited with code 1
16:38:09 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Couldn't find a solution somewhere else, they are all related to different things.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Could solve it manually creating the necessary folders, then the server process could create the pid file.

```
mkdir -p tmp/pids
```

Comment: Isn't it weird that it needs to be solved manually, while rails uses `tmp/pids/server.pid` as the default location for puma pidfile?

Comment: Rails automatically creates the folder during initialization when you start the server with `bundle exec rails server (puma)`.
This folder creation will be skipped if you start the server with `bundle exec puma`, resulting in the error.
It would be nice though if both commands had the same result, saves some errors like these.

Comment: Just as an aside, if your app needs to be pushed to a server (for example Heroku), and if you previously had /tmp/* in your .gitignore you need to add a .keep file to the pids folder, re-add the pids folder (and the .keep file) to the git repo using `git add -f`, and add an exclusion to .gitignore to not exclude the pids folder and the .keep file.

Comment: `mkdir -p tmp/pids` create recursively

Comment: Don't forget to update your `.dockerignore` file when you update your `.gitignore` to allow the new path to make it into your docker image.

Answer (score 9):

This error happened when I first added `puma.rb` file by `rails app:update` to rails 5.2 for a Heroku app.

```rb
# Specifies the `pidfile` that Puma will use.
pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }
```

Resolved by adding `tmp/pids/.keep` file,

```sh
$ touch tmp/pids/.keep
```

And updating `.gitignore` file as follows.

```sh
# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*
/tmp/*
!/log/.keep
!/tmp/.keep

# Ignore pidfiles, but keep the directory.
/tmp/pids/*
!/tmp/pids/
!/tmp/pids/.keep
```

Comment: I feel this is the better solution (although I confess I needed a fast fix so I manually created the directory  )

Answer (score 3):

You can add that in your `config/puma.rb`:

```rb
require "fileutils"
FileUtils.mkdir_p("tmp/pids")
```

Answer (score 0):

A better answer would be to not be calling `puma` directly but calling `rails server`.

e.g. instead of:

```bash
bundle exec puma -p $PORT -C ./config/puma.rb
```

Do:

```bash
unset PORT && bundle exec rails server
```

For instance in a Procfile/Procfile.dev

```
web: unset PORT && bundle exec rails server
css: yarn build:css --watch
worker: bundle exec rails jobs:work
```